# Using Jquery Change text on input field based on another text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('#query').change(function() {
  if ($("#query").text() == "Kiran") {
    var val =
      $('#change').val()
  } else {
    $('#change').text("Kiran Kumar")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="change" value="Kiran">
<input type="text" id="query" value="Kiran Kumar">
```

Suppose, there are two input field with text. Kiran and Kiran Kumar

Whenever i change text Kiran into Kumar...then change another text field is Kumar Kumar.

Comment: Inputs should  .val() not .text().

Answer (score 2):

as Steve said, your problem is you're using `.text()` and not `.val()`.

Text doesn't work because your value is on input.value so you have to use `.val();`
When you have an span with a value inside for example:

```
<span id="span-id"> value </span>
```

You can get 'value' with:

```
$('span-id').text();`
```

Your code, if I understood correctly, just changing text to val, is working.
I post an example on jsfiddle working.

```js
$('#query').on('change input', function(){
    const queryVal = $('#query')
   if (queryVal.val() == "Kiran") {
      $('#change').val(queryVal.val());
    } else {
      $('#change').val("Kiran Kumar")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="change" value="Kiran">
<input type="text" id="query" value="Kiran Kumar">
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzkq7x2h/10/)

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#change").change(function(){
        $('#query').val($('#change').val() +" Kumar") ;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="change" value="Kiran">
<input type="text" id="query" value="Kiran Kumar">
</body>
</html>
```